# How to print IO String - "Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘[Char]’ Expected type: String Actual type: IO String"

Tags: haskell, io, stdout

I want this function to print a given `IO String`

```hs
day :: IO String -> IO ()
day p2 = do
  putStr "p2: "
  putStrLn p2
```

But the compiler says that it needs `[Char]`, but from what I know it's basically the same as `String`, so my question is **how do I print out `IO String`?**

Also this is what the error that `stack run` outputs:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: IO String
    • In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘p2’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn p2
      In the expression: do putStrLn p2    • Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: IO String
    • In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘p2’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn p2
      In the expression: do putStrLn p2
   |
17 |   putStrLn p2
   |            ^^
```

I tried doing `putStr ("p2: " ++ p2)` and using `print` but with no success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler's error message is actually very clear. The argument to `putStrLn` has to be a `String` (or `[Char]`, the two types are synonyms of each other), but your `p2` is not a `String` but an `IO String`.

The same fundamental error occurs in both of the other things you say you have tried - they can't get round this issue.

It's not totally clear what you want to do. I see two possibilities:

- if you simply want to print out a string, then you don't want the input to be an `IO String` at all, but a simple `String`. If you simply change the type signature accordingly, this will compile with no problem.
- perhaps you do indeed want to take an action of type `IO String` (such as `getLine`) as an input. In that case, you can use `do` notation (which you're already using anyway) to bind the *output* of the action, which is an actual `String`, to a variable and then call `putStrLn` with that:

  ```
  day :: IO String -> IO ()
  day p2 = do
     putStr "p2: "
     s <- p2
     putStrLn s
  ```

Comment: thank you very much, i thought that when i already read from file in another function (with binding) i don't have to bind again

Comment: binding with `v <- action` (at least in the IO context) basically means "run the action `action` and store its result in the variable `v`". Reading from a file is indeed such an action which you can bind to the result of, but it doesn't make any sense to think that this stops you from binding to the results of any subsequent actions you may use. (And I encourage you to read about monads in Haskell, which will show you what's "really" going on here, and how, although `do` notation may look like a sequence of "statements" as in imperative programming, it's all just expressions under the hood.)